# Simple JQuery getJSON is not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, getjson, simplegeo

I am trying to read in the category list from SimpleGeo...  my code works fine in Chrome and FireFox, but fails in IE.

```
$.getJSON("http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/categories.json",function(json){
    sgCategories = json;
});
```

Looking at a couple other posts seem to offer ideas but the API doesn't seem to offer a callback and I have no control of their format...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514457/getjson-or-ajax-requests-not-working-with-ie9
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517608/why-isnt-this-simple-bit-of-jquery-getjson-working-in-ie8

Any other ideas?

Comment: Looks like a cross-domain request. Perhaps IE doesn't support cross-domain requests?

Comment: I cannot check with api doc now, but isn't second arg in that func data to post? Try add null as second arg, I'm probably wrong but it is a few seconds check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...   it turns out that SimpleGeo allows you to get the category list via their javascript client api.

```
var sgClient = new simplegeo.Client('yourAccessKey');
sgClient.getFeatureCategories(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        sgCategories = data;
    };
});
```

Tricky...

Answer (score 1):

Based on one of those links you have cited, it appears there may be a work around.

Try adding `&format=jsonp&callback=?` to the URL.

I think jQuery might call the callback you specify anyway if you add the callback parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding either or both causes it to fail in all browsers...  it seems they aren't supported by the SimpleGeo API.  Trying to find a work around...   vexing as it works great in all but IE and I can easily see the data by going to: [http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/categories.json](http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/categories.json)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.support.cors = true;
that's it